# How to make class generics optional in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

So I know about the optional arguments in TS
but I wonder how can I make generic of class optional
like this one which is my code

```
export class TableColumn<T, P? extends keyof T> {}
```

and I can't even make multiple class with the same name to do it like this

```
 export class TableColumn<T, P extends keyof T> {}
 export class TableColumn<T, P extends keyof T, S extends keyof T> {}
```

so any help?
both solutions can help but I don't know why not working

> Update

I am working on this library

https://simplex24.de/smc-demo/direct-edit

and it's a generic table creator for the angular material table
the problem with the library is that for each column it just get one value of the model

```
new TableColumn<TestData, 'id'>('My ID', 'id');
```

but I need more and if I don't make it optional 
then I should add to all columns like this

```
new TableColumn<TestData, 'aa','aa','aa'>('My aa', 'aa', 'aa', 'aa');
new TableColumn<TestData, 'bb', 'bb', 'bb'>('My bb', 'bb', 'bb', 'bb');
new TableColumn<TestData, 'cc', 'bb', 'aa'>('My cc', 'cc', 'bb', 'aa');
```

for the first and second columns import aa and bb because it's not optional
I can make it optional easily like this one

```
new TableColumn<TestData, 'aa','aa','aa'>('My aa', 'aa',);
new TableColumn<TestData, 'bb','aa','aa'>('My bb', 'bb');
new TableColumn<TestData, 'cc', 'bb', 'aa'>('My cc', 'cc', 'bb', 'aa');
```

but as U can see I need to add them in generic in class because I couldn't make it generic optional

need to be like this

```
new TableColumn<TestData, 'aa'>('My aa', 'aa',);
new TableColumn<TestData, 'bb'>('My bb', 'bb');
new TableColumn<TestData, 'cc', 'bb', 'aa'>('My cc', 'cc', 'bb', 'aa');
```

Comment: Sounds like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to solve by having optional generics?

Comment: I wonder if the first solution is possible? the goal is cleaner code instead of making multiple class with multiple name

Comment: Try to use a default value, e.g. `export class TableColumnOne<T, P extends keyof T, S extends (keyof T|never) = never>{}

Comment: @alirezas you *shouldn't* need multiple classes with multiple names. You likely shouldn't need optional generics. If you tell us what is the core of the problem, then we might give you a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use **Never** type that's the way U can use

```
export class TableColumn<T,
P extends keyof T,
Z extends (keyof T | never) = never,
Y extends (keyof T | never) = never,
X extends (keyof T | never) = never,
W extends (keyof T | never) = never> {}
```

and in the constructor, it's easily possible like this

```
constructor(public property: P,
public secondProperty?: Z, public thirdProperty?: Y,
public fourthProperty?: X, public fifthProperty?: W) {}
```

Comment: u just save my day tank U